# Unit test SQS receiveMessage with Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, aws-sdk, aws-cli

Having trouble figuring out how to unit test this, i come close but can't quite solve it.

Here is the function:

```
 receiveMessage(callback: Function): any {
    this.sqs.receiveMessage(
      this.params,
      (err: AWSError, data: ReceiveMessageResult) => callback(err, data)
    );
  }
```

In the test i setup the initial AWS mock and override it in the test:

```
jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
  const SQSMocked = {
    receiveMessage: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
  };
  return {
    SQS: jest.fn(() => SQSMocked),
    config: {
      update: jest.fn(() => {
        return { region: getConfig().region };
      })
    }
  };
});

const sqs = new AWS.SQS({
  region: 'us-east-1'
});
```

Then the actual test is done here. I think i'm going wrong when overriding the receiveMessage on the aws sdk.

```
  it('checks the callback is called', (done) => {
    const callback = (err: AWSError, data: ReceiveMessageResult) => {
      console.log('called');
      done();
    };

    // how to call the callback on the mock???
    sqs.receiveMessage = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(callback);

    sqsQueue.receiveMessage(callback);

    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I've tried many combinations of overriding the aws sdk, most times typescript errors but can't quite seem to figure out how to mock the function callback.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you initialize `this.sqs`? Please provide minimal, completed  code

Answer (score 0):

I changed the main function and extracted the callback interface:

```
  receiveMessage(callback: SqsCallback): void {
    this.sqs.receiveMessage(this.params, callback);
  }
```

Now the test just checks the callback is called:

```
  it('should call the callback', (done) => {
    const callback: SqsCallback = jest.fn(
      (err: AWSError, data: ReceiveMessageResult) => {
        done();
      }
    );
    const receiveMessageMock = jest.fn((expectedConfig, sqsCallback) => {
      return sqsCallback();
    });
    // @ts-ignore
    sqs.receiveMessage = receiveMessageMock;

    sqsQueue.receiveMessage(callback);
  });
```

I was unable to avoid the TS type check so had to put the ts-ignore over the mock.

Hard to get one's head around the concept on first attempt but got there after a couple of days :)